# python - best way to call a variable between files?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have have a view setup in DRF -

views.py

```
class APIDetail(APIView):
    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
        query = model.objects.get(id=pk)

....
```

I essentially want to pass that pk as a variable into my renderer which is below -

renderers.py

```
def render(self, data, accepted_media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
    if data is None:
        return ''

    stream = StringIO()

    xml = SimplerXMLGenerator(stream, self.charset)
    xml.startDocument()
    xml.startElement("job id='string1' name='string2'",{})
```

I'm thinking it would be something as simple as making my class in views.py to be like so -

```
class APIDetail(APIView):
    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
        def jobid():
            global pk
            return pk
        query = model.objects.get(id=pk)

....
```

and then somehow pass that global variable into the renderers.py but I'm not sure how to do that.  I'm guessing something like this but it doesn't work.

```
def render(self, data, accepted_media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
    if data is None:
        return ''

    stream = StringIO()

    xml = SimplerXMLGenerator(stream, self.charset)
    xml.startDocument()
    xml.startElement("job id='string1' name='string2'",{}) [jobid]
```

All I keep getting is global name 'jobid' is not defined.

Comment: can you inspect `data` in your renderer?

Comment: the renderer works fine with the data being passed and the pk is a valid jobid.  I just want to pass it separately as a variable to call in another location in the custom xml I'm rendering.

Comment: This question is very unclear. Global variables are nearly always a bad idea, especially in a multi-user environment like a Django project. But what exactly are you trying to do? Why can't you simply pass the ID to your renderer?

Answer (score 0):

Going by @DanielRoseman's concerns I've decided to approach this differently.  I'm altering the view to pass in the line directly at which point I'll figure out how to pass the entire data to renderer after.  This was the variables are all passed locally inside the view only to be rendered through a custom renderer.

Answer (score -1):

you need to declare the `jobid` variable as a global, thusly: `global jobid` in the `render` function itself.  I'm assuming it's correctly defined elsewhere.

edited to clear up the comment below:

```
def render(self, data, accepted_media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
    global jobid ###this is what you need to add
    if data is None:
        return ''

    stream = StringIO()

    xml = SimplerXMLGenerator(stream, self.charset)
    xml.startDocument()
    xml.startElement("job id='string1' name='string2'",{}) [jobid]
```

Comment: ok I called it in my views.py as a global function as per the above.  I tried to change the line in the render to [global jobid] and now it complains "invalid syntax" on that line.

Comment: No, you really don't want to do this. Firstly, `global` means within a single file, so doesn't solve the OP's problem; and secondly, you'd then get all sorts of thread-safety issues. Don't do it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman - what would the alternative be then?  I already have the view passing "data" to the renderer how could I get it to also pass "pk"?